# Waterfox automatically Google searching while still typing in address bar

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, google-search, address-bar, waterfox

I have the strangest problem I can't seem to find anyone else online having.

While typing (as in **without** pressing 'enter') anything in the address bar, not 3 characters into my string, the page automatically redirects to any random webpage title match found from my history, and anything not matching a title redirects to a Google search.

Here's the thing: I don't have Google search. I use DuckDuckGo, then Startpage, then Disconnect, and Google is not on my list of search engines.

Using Waterfox 56.2.11

Addons (";" delimiter):

Add-ons Manager
Context Menu 0.4.2.1-signed.1-signed;
ChatZilla 0.9.93;
Cleanest Addon Manager 7.1;
Disconnect 5.18.27;
Disconnect Search 1.4.1.1-signed.1-signed;
Download Status Bar 15.0.0.1;
Download Statusbar 0.9.10.1-signed.1-signed;
DownThemAll! 3.0.8;
Emoji Stickers Postcards Emoticons 3.2;
Fastest Search 3.39.2;
FoxyProxy Standard 4.6.5;
Ghostery – Privacy Ad Blocker 8.3.4;
Greasemonkey 4.1;
HTTPS Everywhere 2019.6.4;
InvisibleHand 6.6;
Lazarus: Form Recovery 2.3.1-signed.1-signed;
NoScript 5.1.8.4;
RAMBack 1.0.1-signed.1-signed;
RightToClick 2.9.5.1-signed;
ScrapBook 1.5.14;
Screengrab! 2.18;
Secret Agent 1.35;
Send Tab URLs 2.3.1;
SoundCloud Downloader - Technowise 0.98;
StumbleUpon 4.21;
Tab Mix Plus 0.5.5.0;
Tamper Data 11.0.1.1-signed.1-signed;
Turn Off the Lights 4.0.37.0;
Video DownloadHelper 7.3.6;
Video Speed Controller 0.5.1

Comment: Disable all the extensions. Does the problem go away? If so, enable extensions beginning with A-H. Does the problem recur? Lather, rinse, repeat. If, the problem does not recur, great, you solved it. If disabling extensions did not solve the problem, then have you made any changes to the ABOUT: settings in Waterfox recently?

Comment: Yeah I neglected to do that basic first step, and am surprised to find Fastest Search 3.39.2 was the problem, which is strange, because it is only meant for searching within a webpage, and has nothing to do with the address bar.
Thanks for your reply and reminder to do basic steps!

Comment: "… only meant for searching within a webpage …" – the extension has a much broader scope, please see for example https://www.reddit.com/r/waterfox/comments/ccixu1/-/etowy3q/

Comment: "… Lather, rinse, repeat. …" – an extension can automate the routine. [Extension Conflict Troubleshooter : waterfox](https://www.reddit.com/r/waterfox/comments/93x02v/extension_conflict_troubleshooter/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After restarting in safe mode/disabling all addons (Help... > Restart with Add-ons Disabled), an addon was revealed to be the cause, and after narrowing it down, found Fastest Search 3.39.2 was the problem.

I will be reporting it to their team.

Comment: http://www.mingyi.org/FastestSearch/index.html